# Unable to add a dynamic attribute to a Spring form:input tag

Tags: forms, spring, dynamic-attributes

I have a Spring form tag and am trying to add a dynamic attribute (the "placeholder" attribute), but get the following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/work.jsp (line: 290, column: 3) 
Attribute placeholder invalid for tag textarea according to TLD
```

The jsp:

```
<form:input path="name" cssClass="input-xlarge" id="name" placeholder="type your name"/>
```

According to: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5931 dynamic attributes are supported in Spring 3.0 (depending on JSP 2.0) which I belive I have.

My environment:

```
Java: 1.6.0_29
Tomcat: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
Servlet: 3.0
Spring : 3.0.7.RELEASE
JSP Engine: 2.1
```

Comment: I discovered that even though I am using Spring version 3.0* my form taglib was from verison 2.0  because spring-2.0-m5.jar was in my lib folder. When I got rid of that my dynamic attributes started working propertly.

*the following code reported the Spring version to 3.0.7.RELEASE : org.springframework.core.SpringVersion.getVersion( )

Comment: I will *answer* my question when stackoverflow allows me in 8 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that even though I am using Spring version 3.0*, my form taglib was from verison 2.0  becauswas spring-2.0-m5.jar was in my lib folder. When I removed it, the form tag rendered with the "placeholder" attribute).

*the following code reported the Spring version to 3.0.7.RELEASE : org.springframework.core.SpringVersion.getVersion( )